# Rigging - Sword like object influenced by 2 bones

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

As in topic. How to attach a sword to have it be influenced by two bones. Not off course in the same time. 
I was fighting with "child-of" constraint, but with no luck. Well it works, but if I was in need to change bone influence form pelvis to left hand, it just fly away somewhere, so the transition wasn't seamless as I was expecting. I really don't have any idea on how to do this. I was experimenting a lot.

Basically Sword bone must follow pelvis bone, when it's not used, and need to follow hand bone, when the animation need it. Anyone, because it's driving Me crazy. It can even be via payed addon, anything.

Regards! :)

Comment: You do want child-of.  But you have to know that child-of doesn't replace parenting, it adds to it.  If you want it sometimes be the child of one bone, and at other times another, make it root level, with 2 different child of constraints.  Use "apply visual transform" and set inverse and apply visual transforms to control the transition.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only to be one parent switch, the [Child of Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/child_of.html) should do that, but for multiple switches or just plain simplicity, I'd be looking at (as you mentioned) visually switching between two swords, or even easier - splitting the project up between two or more Blend files, each taking over from the previous and each with the correct parent assigned. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)

The transition would be simple enough.  As the hand would firstly have to move to the sword's handle you'd need to animate that in the 1st file with the pelvis as the parent.  Once the sword handle is gripped, that would be where the next Blend file takes over and with that running, the hand is the parent.

A similar case is here:
[How can I copy animation from an object while it was attached as a child and then paste that animation to it after detaching it?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202560/how-can-i-copy-animation-from-an-object-while-it-was-attached-as-a-child-and-the/203010#203010)

Answer (score -1):

I've not done much animation so take this recommendation with a grain of salt.

I think you want to keyframe the influence of one set (say Sword & Hand) to 1 when drawn. And 0 when stowed?

This tutorial may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9FJOR_Q_MQ

Comment: I know about that, it goes about the same, but with pelvis movement. Then We have double transformation. And animating influence needs also animating frame by frame sword position. I'm thinking about adding 2 swords and animate its visibility.

Comment: That would be my other recommendation, but not sure how it may look in post.