# How to let go the object with armature constraint?

Tags: animation, constraints

So I`m doing a scene in which a man is waving with the sword and then he must stick it into the ground (like bownig before someone) and step away (disconnect from the sword). But I dont know how to do it with armature constraint activated. I tried animating strengh parameter by decreasing it but it changes the object orient.
Anything i can do?
Also bonus question: Can I stop objects from going through the body from time to time? I thought it has something to do with rigid body, but did not work it out.

Comment: This might be helpful -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202560/how-can-i-copy-animation-from-an-object-while-it-was-attached-as-a-child-and-the/203010#203010 ---

Also this -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174898/rigging-sword-like-object-influenced-by-2-bones/210795#210795

Comment: seems so, thanks! I`ll read it soon